# Send a block to octave from emacs

Tags: emacs, octave

I am quite new to emacs, and am trying to get it to work with octave. I have read through the tutorial on the octave site

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Running-Octave-from-Within-Emacs.html#Running-Octave-from-Within-Emacs

and so far have been able to get emacs to open *Inferior Octave* as well as get emacs to switch into octave mode when I load a .m file

My problem I cannot send my code from my .m file and get it to run in octave. If I open terminal and type

```
octave filename.m
```

Octave runs fine. I understand that I should be able to send it directly to octave from emacs, or even send just a block of my code. I do not understand how to do this. The commands on the website I posted above do not work. For example, if I try to type

```
C-c i b
```

Before I can type "b" it says "i is undefined". Can someone give me a hand with this?

Can someone give me a newbie explanation on how to do this? I want to learn emacs, but I can only learn it by using it, and right now I am unable to get my TeX and Octave work done on it at all!

**EDIT:**

Oops. I just realized that I needed C-c Tab b. My block is now sending to octave. But the plot I want is not showing up anywhere!

my file is called plot.m. It looks like this

```
x = 0:0.05:1;
plot(x, sin(x));
```

and when I am over that block. Typing C-c Tab-b seems to send it to *Octave Inferior*, but then nothing happens (in terminal, usually AquaTerm would open with my plot)

Comment: In my version of emacs the binding is: C-c Tab b to send a block.

Comment: I tried `C-c Tab b` but I got `up-list: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 1, 1` error. Try sending one line at a time by doing `C-c tab l` this worked for me and also popped up a plot.

Comment: I have the same issue with run-block on octave and I can't seem to solve it anyhow. I could really use the run block functionality since run region is sometimes a pain to use. Any help will be appreciated!